# CSS: How to position span or div inside anchor

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this situation:

```
<li id="liMessagesPanel" >
    <span id="unreadMessagesCount" class="messagesCount" ></span>
    <a ID="lnkMessages" class="messages">
        <small>Notifications</small>
    </a>
</li>
```

This produces the following:
[image]

```
a.messages{ background: url(../img/Footer/iconMail.png) no-repeat center center; border-right: 1px solid #bbb;}

.messagesCount {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 16% 16% 16% 16%;
    color: White;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 198px;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    padding: 0 1px;
}
```

The problem is that because the span is not inside the anchor element it's not clickable, and if I put it inside the anchor element it's not recognized.

The white mail envelope is the image, the red box on the upper right of the envelope image is the span.

Note: I cannot change the structure li -> a -> small because it is used by a jquery plugin, the span was an addition of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `position: absolute;` on `.messageCount`, you can put it inside of your `<a>` tag.

Note: I only added `href="#"` in the `<a>` tag so that it shows that everything is a clickable link.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wk3yU/3/)

Html:

```
<li id="liMessagesPanel" >
    <a ID="lnkMessages" class="messages" href="#">
        <small>Notifications</small>            
        <span id="unreadMessagesCount" class="messagesCount" ></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Css:

```
a.messages{ a.messages{ background: url(../img/Footer/iconMail.png) no-repeat center center; border-right: 1px solid #bbb;}

#lnkMessages {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.messages {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
}

.messagesCount {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 16% 16% 16% 16%;
    color: White;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    width: 18px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    /* new: */
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution was the best.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to handle a click event on the span. then you can do what ever you wish when the span is clicked

```
 $("#unreadMessagesCount").click(function(){
       //do what ever


 });
```

you can use css to change the cursor on mouse over of the span so the user knows it is clickable

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the span clickable?

```
$('liMessagesPanel>span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().click();
});
```

Assumes the use of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Add css to make cursor pointer appear for your `<span>`:

```
.messagesCount { 
   cursor: pointer;
   ...
   ...
```

And then make the `<span>` click handler to trigger the `<a>` click handler:

```
$('.messagesCount').click(function() {
   $(this).next('a').triggerHandler('click');
});
```